# Twitter Link Count from Twitter REST API

Tags: twitter

Is there a way to get the link count from twitter to implement our own version of a tweet button? From the official Twitter API.

PS:Search API only works for a limited amount of time.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this

http://urls.api.twitter.com/1/urls/count.json?
url=http://someLink.com&callback=twttr.receiveCount

Comment: Blimey mate! Thanks... I had given up on this one!

Comment: This API is private only and you are not allowed to use this! (https://dev.twitter.com/discussions/5839)

Comment: I think it doesn't work anymore, all it display now is: message: "Sorry, that page does not exist"