# Twitter: Rate limit exceeded, do tweet buttons count as a request?

Tags: json, caching, twitter, twitter-feed

I've got a twitter feed that caches a request from twitter. At most it gets the feed every 10 minutes (so that's 6 times an hour out of the max limit of 150).

I regularly get issues when the rate limit is exceed. The only reason I can think of that could be causing this is because of the tweet buttons used elsewhere on the site.

Does using a tweet button count as a request, and if so, what's the best way to cache the results?

I'm using the json request:
http://twitter.com/status/user_timeline/USER_ACCOUNT.json?count=2

Answer (score 1):

What you want to do is use this request for your tweet buttons, I don't think it's rate limited.

http://urls.api.twitter.com/1/urls/count.json?url=http://someLink.com&callback=twttr.receiveCount

[Twitter Link Count from Twitter REST API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3960727/twitter-link-count-from-twitter-rest-api)

Comment: I use the link above for the tweet buttons, and link I posted for the feed. I'm still reaching a max limit.

Comment: I don't know then, what you can also try is to whitelist your app where it will open you up to 20,000 requests per hour. I hear the application process is fairly lenient. Btw, the user timeline IS rate limited so that probably explains it. I don't think it's your tweet buttons. https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1/get/statuses/user_timeline

Comment: I've been requesting tweet counts from this url for many thousands requests now without any delay between them and I haven't been blacklisted so far.
What I've seen though is that after ~250 requests the server seems to have added some kind of delay between the responses (~0.25seconds), but still no ban or whatever.
So yeah it feels pretty safe to say that this url is not rate limited.